# Using bonding in debian 9?

Tags: linux, bonding

debian 9 is installed by default without net-tools (deprecated).
If you try to install ifenslave, it will install net-tools (i don't wan't this).
How can i do this ?

Comment: Rebuild the package without depending on net-tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally done by installing ifenslave (come with net-tools), and following tutorial

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding